# React Redux, write unit test for an ajax request

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, jestjs, enzyme

I am writing test cases for a component which triggers an ajax request in the `componentDidMount()`. On completion of the request I trigger a redux action to update the state (which updates the UI using props).

```
componentDidMount() {
    this.props.requestCurrenciesWithRates();
    return axios
      .post(this.props.serverUrl + `/api`, {
        action: 'GET_CURRENCIES_WITH_RATES',
        data: {},
        meta: {}
      })
      .then(res => {
        let { accountCurrencies, currencyRates } = res.data.payload;
        // redux action
        this.props.receiveCurrenciesWithRates(accountCurrencies, currencyRates);
      })
      .catch(error => {
        // handle error
        // redux action 
        this.props.appError(error.message);
      });
  }
```

I want to write a unit test to test the updating of the ui. I am using `jest`, `enzyme` to test

```
const apiSetup = () => {
  const {wrapper, store} = providers(<Component />)
  const page = mount(wrapper);
  // I am mocking the api using jest.mock 
  const apiPromise = axios
    .post(`/api`, {
      action: 'GET_CURRENCIES_WITH_RATES',
      data: {},
      meta: {}
    })
    .then(res => {
       chai
            .expect(
              page.find('TopUpCurrencies').find('.tcm-available-currency-tab')
            )
            .to.have.lengthOf(2);
          chai
            .expect(page.find('TopUpCurrencies').find('.tcm-currency-rate-tab'))
            .to.have.lengthOf(8);
    });

  return { page, apiPromise };
};
```

But the view is never updated. Is there a way to verify the view after the action is triggered and the view is updated?